# jQuery slider fails to load first image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having problems with my slider when it comes to loading first page. When i'm using the "left" or "right" arrow under the images and then go back to first page everything is working. Got no idea where can i fix it.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/f7770oLf/1/

And actually i'm not sure if it's because of CSS or jQuery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS loads in the order it is coded.  You are overwriting your `.active-slide` with the `.slide` class which disables the `display: block;` you're looking for.  To make it all work, move:

```
.active-slide 
{
    display: block;
}
```

below

```
.slide 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You override the `.slide .active-slide`s visibility property by defining `.slide` as hidden afterwords. This makes the first slide invisible, since there's no jQuery call to make it visible. Change:

```
.active-slide 
{
  display: block;
}

.slider 
{
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 669px;
}

.slide 
{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So that `.active-slide` is *after* `.slide`:

```
.slider 
{
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 669px;
}

.slide 
{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.active-slide 
{
  display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/f7770oLf/2/).